# Install external C++ libraries into Clion for a C++ project under Windows 7

Tags: c++, clion, odeint

I am new to Clion and C++ and your help is highly appreciated!!

My goal was to download a library to solve Ordinary Differential Equations.
The zip file was downloaded from http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/downloads.html
and unzipped in `D:\myProjects\odeint`. I use Windows 7 and MinGW.

The library can't be used as shown in the following image.
[image]

Here are the error reports.

```
D:\myProjects\main.cpp:3:51: fatal error: odeint/include/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\myProjects.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/myProjects.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/myProjects.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/myProjects.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myProjects.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/myProjects.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/myProjects.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [myProjects] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'myProjects' failed
```

Comment: You should add the content of `CMakeLists.txt` to your question.

Comment: I am new to the CMake. May I know what I should write? Here is my current CMakeList.txt

Comment: Here is my current CMakeList.txt cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(myProjects)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -

std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp test.h test.cpp)
add_executable(myProjects ${SOURCE_FILES})